# How to use font-display: swap; for roboto font quasar application

Tags: webpack, quasar-framework, quasar

Currently I am using `‘roboto-font’` in my `quasar.config`

```
extras: [
      'roboto-font'
    ],
```

but when I run chrome light house score on my web it gives me

> Ensure text remains visible during webfont load issue

which requires `font-display: swap;` in `@font-face` but if I look into my build there are `@font-face{font-family:Roboto;font-style:normal;font-weight:300;src:url(../fonts/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBBc-.865f928c.woff) format("woff")}` kind of font-face configuration in `vendor.js`. How can I make CLI to add font-swap for font loading time?

Answer (score 1):

Comment out `'roboto-font'` in `extras` and add this to your `index.template.html`:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700;900&display=swap" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
<noscript><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"></noscript>
```

The extra code for the "Eliminate Render Blocking Resources" that Lighthouse will give you if you only add the font link:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

https://web.dev/render-blocking-resources/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=devtools